# Trying to find(guess) game formula

Tags: math, game-engine, formula, linear-algebra

Hello I'm trying to find a Formula of a certain system(Game) and would like some help.

I will try not to get into the context of the game too much, but some times it will be necessary for better understanding the situation.

It's a kinda long text, but bear with me! this game exists for 12 years now and no one has ever tried to decipher it (or at least published the results)

I'm certain the game is mostly done in **C++** if that helps...

Facts :

1) It's a mix of percentage and flat values of unknown order

2) I don't know what the actual base value is, and is likely that other invisible bonuses exists

3) Finding all the bonuses is irrelevant, only finding a working algorithm for public use

4) I can gather an indefinite amount of example equations

5) I have 10 equipment slots + 1 weapon slot , each equipment can have a certain % bonus, and the weapon can have a certain flat bonus

---

For now i'm assuming the general formula is

```
(baseValue + flatBonuses)*(sumOfAllPercentageBonuses/100 + 1) =finalTotal
```

---

Equation examples :

The main issue i'm having here, is that when I remove all equipment+weapon pieces, It seems that the number I see is not actually the base value, hence why :

*2170 is the lowest value I can visually see removing all equipment*

```
(2170)*(1.22) = 2543 is false
```

But I think it's safe to assume 2170 is close to the actual base damage since it's increasing 17% from said 22%

The weapon most likely has a modifier to it's flat value :

309 here is the weapon flat damage

```
 2170 + 309*weaponModifier = 2685
```

Another weapon :

```
2170 + 34*weaponModifier = 2226
```

Considering 2170 should be close to the actual base damage, and the weapon modifiers using 2170 give around 1.6ish, we could assume the weapon modifier is 1.6 with a low error margin.

And it's possible that the percentages are not actually summed :

again , starting from 2170 :

- with 1 equipment giving 22% each I achieve 2543 final value
- with 2 equipments giving 22% each I achieve 2993 final value

---

Highest value visually achieved applying the general assumed formula:

Equipments :

- 4x22%
- 1x19%
- 1x159%
- 1x105%

total 379%

- 1x494 (weapon)

  (actualBaseBalue + otherFlatBonuses + 494*weaponModifier)*(4.79) = 12,908

I'm not asking for anyone to make the hard work for me, but I'm not a mathematician. I have been trying this for 2 hours with no results, if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate them very much! thanks for reading.

If anyone is interested in additional info or screenshots even, just ask.

Comment: what does this have to do with mathematica or c++?

Comment: mathematica was a mistake, edited

Comment: What's 309 ? (when you talk about weapon modifiers). Is it the value that becomes 494 later ? Can you gather data with several different weapons ? Do you have something like skill levels that are corresponding to equipments / weapons ? These might come into play. In that case you should try different weapon values of exactly the same kind/skill. And out of curiosity, what game is it ?

Comment: Also, what's the 4.79 in your last formula ?

Comment: @Cimbali 309 and 494 are two different weapons, no skill level depending to weapon, 4.79 is the sum of all percentages (379%) in decimal form+1, skills are already maxed and have no connection to the weapon. the game is called With your Destiny or Supreme Destiny in Asia. there are multiple "Magic skills" with different base value that I mainly used to determine whether something is scaling or linear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: alright, removed c++ tag...

Comment: @rightføld well he's asking for an algorithm to find the formula, after all.

Comment: Being a math question this should be posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several hypothesis can be made. Supposing you have two kinds of bonuses, flat and percentage, thus respectively additive and multiplicative bonuses. Let `b` be the base value, `a` an additive bonus, `m` a multiplicative one -- in the way you defined it, thus need to multiply by `(m+1)`.

- additive bonuses can be applied before multiplicative, as you supposed `(a+b) * (m+1)`
- the opposite `b*(m+1) + a`
- both (e.g. one bonus to strength before, one bonus to damage afterwards) `(a+b) * (m+1) + a'`
- several multiplicative bonuses can be added : `b * (1+m+m')`
- several multiplicative bonuses can be multiplied : `b * (1+m) * (1+m')`

The tricky part is there are many parameters, and any combination of the above could be valid. Even though or your skills are "maxed out" as you say (thus constant throughout the experiments), they might still come into play by modifying or ponderating the values, say with `p` a ponderation factor, `b * (1+pm)` or `b * p(1+m)`.

What I would suggest, is the following :

- For each kind of equipment, try to find out it is multiplicative or additive.

  - Try to find pieces of equipment that have no special things attached (no "enchanted" extra bonuses or whatever). Let us note `v` the value of each experiment.
  - You'll need at least 2 pieces of equipment as similar as you can get them, with different values `x`. The more experiments, the more points you have to figure out which of the following laws is constant (or linear in `x`, if you don't divide by it * ).

    - If the bonus of this piece of equipment is additive, then `(v - b) / x` is constant.
    - If the bonus of this piece of equipment is multiplicative, then `v / (b * (1+x))` is constant.
    - If the bonus of this piece of equipment is with ponderation before adding 1 to m, then `(v / b - 1) / x` is constant.
- Now you have a law for each separate kind of equipment, try mixing them up. Let us note `b` the base value `v1` and `v2` the values of the different equipments (separately), and `v` the value of the new experiment.

  - If bonuses add up, `v = b + (v1 - b)  + (v2 - b)` (this works for two additive laws, or an additive law applied after a multiplicative law)
  - If bonuses multiply, `v1 / b = v2 / v1`, for example 2543 / 2170 ~= 2993 / 2543 ~= 1.17 (this works for two multiplicative laws, or an multiplicative law applied after an additive law)

And so on. Basically, try to explore the space of possibilities for combinations to get a value, see what it would mean (i.e. try to foresee the values) and then experiment, until you get the right model. And remember the order in which bonuses are applied matters as soon as you have several items. As long as you add one item at a time, you should be fine.

---

* Don't forget your output values are int's, thus rounded values of the formula's outputs. I would recommend getting as much as possible every time, and trying to plot each curve `(v-b) = f(x)`, `v/b = f( (1+x) )`, `(v/b - 1) = f(x)`, and look -or fit a model- to see which is linear. If there is a ponderation of some kind, it will be the slope of this line.

Comment: Thanks alot for that Cimbali, on a side note; the game is very simplified, there are no special values or categories, the only thing that modifies magic damage seems to be the percentages on the equipments and the weapon's flat value, I will try with other characters what you said, hopefully slowly getting to a pattern here.

Comment: What makes me say that is that cumulating your 22% equipments seems to give a 17% increase every time, so something more complicated than just `* (1 + 22 / 100)` happens there.